# SUMIF/SUMIFS in array formula

Tags: excel

I have this **Array formula** that Works good:

```
{=SUM(IF(Range1="L";Range*Range))/SUM(IF(Range1="L";Range))}
```

But if I change *SUM(IF* to *SUMIF* doesn't work I don't know why.

```
{=SUMIF(Range1;"L";Range*Range)/SUMIF(Range1;"L";Range)}
```

And I want to put *SUMIFS*, because I want to add a new IF in the first formula, like this:

```
{=SUMIFS(Range*Range;Range1;"L";Range2;"N")/SUMIFS(Range*Range;Range1;"L";Range2;"N")}
```

What I can do to put two ifs in the array formula?

Comment: `{=SUMIFS(Range*Range;Range1;"L";Range2;"N")/SUMIFS(Range*Range;Range1;"L";Range2;"N")} ` would be 1 (or error if 0) anyway, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` are already array formulas (somewhat) and they don't take well to range multiplication. You can use the two criteria in a `SUM(IF`, or in a `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g.

```
=SUM(IF(AND(Range1="L",Range2="N"),Range*Range,0))
=SUMPRODUCT((Range1="L")*(Range2="N")*Range*Range)
```

Comment: It have to return a specific value (the mean of the range) not 1 or 0. I think that the only way to do that is with an array formula

Comment: SUMPRODUCT is an array formula, what is the mathematical formula you're trying to emulate.

Comment: Thank you very much @nutsch